# Get all children of Tkinter python app

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get all the children of Tkinter app.

So far I am using following:

```
_list = root.winfo_children()
```

Which is working fine if I have no notebook widget but once I have added notebook widget I am not able to get the children of notebook widget.

I have even tried with recursion as follows:

```
childlist = []
def all_children (self, wid) :
        _list = wid.winfo_children()    
        for item in _list :
            if item.winfo_children() :
                childlist .extend(item.winfo_children())
                all_children(item)              
            return null
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: we are can't see any notebook widgets !

Comment: Actually i didn't put whole app code

Comment: I found it it's recursion problem. Thank you for your time gentleman

Comment: @мalayмeнтa Answer your own question if you've resolved the issue please.

Comment: i have posted @Nae

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope someone find it useful that's little modification in recursion and can get all children

```
def all_children (self, wid, finList) :
        _list = wid.winfo_children()        
        for item in _list :
            finList.append(item)
            self.all_children(item,finList)   
        return finList
```

Comment: Thanks ! Pretty code ! I will replace the finList with a callback on children, but the logic is awesome (6 lines).

Comment: This can even be improved to a one-line recursive function: `def all_children(widget): return [widget] + [subchild for child in widget.winfo_children() for subchild in all_children(child)]` to get all the children of 'widget', and the widget itself.